# Why is the largest eigenvalue of a laplacian matrix equal to the number of nodes in the graph?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-theory, graph-laplacian

I've been posed the following question:

The spectrum of the Laplacian matrix $Q$ of the complete graph $K_{N}$ on $N$ nodes is:

1. $1^{[1]}$ and $N^{[N-1]}$
2. $0^{[1]}$ and $(N-1)^{N-1}$
3. $1^{[1]}$, $0^{[1]}$, and $(N-1)^{[N-2]}$
4. None of the above.

Here, the $\mu^{[m]}$ denotes multiplicity (how many times that value appears).

My solution to the question would be to choose (4) because the largest eigenvalue of the Laplacian is (by Gerschgorin) $\lambda_{1} \leq d_{max}$ where $d_{max}$ is the largest degree in the graph. The largest degree for a complete graph is $N-1$, (and it is the degree for all nodes in the complete graph). So we should expect to find that the eigenvalues contain at least *one* zero, and all others should be $d_{max}$. That makes the expected correct answer $0^{[1]}$ and $(N-1)^{[N-1]}$

However, apparently the correct answer is: $0^{[1]}$ and $(N)^{[N-1]}$.

Why is the is the case? Have I made a mistake in my graph properties here?

Comment: Gerschgorin tell us the eigenvalues lies inside the closed disc $\bar{B}( d_{max}, d_{max})$, you can only conclude $|\lambda_1| \le 2N-2$, not $N-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laplacian of the complete graph $K_n$ with $n$ nodes is $L_n = n I_n - J_n$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix and $J_n$ is the matrix full of $1$'s. If $v$ is the vector of all 1's, then $L_n v = n v - J_n v = nv - nv = 0$. Also, if $w$ is a vector whose components sum to $0$, then $L_n w = nw - J_n w = nw$. So we can see that indeed the eigenvalues of the Laplacian of $K_n$ are $(0^{[1]}, n^{[n-1]})$.

Comment: I've been trying to follow your answer, but I'm not sure how it relates to your conclusion. Do you think you could clarify a bit? :/

Comment: It shows that there is an eigenvector (all 1’s) with eigenvalue zero, and also shows that when restricted to the subspace of vectors whose components sum to zero, the laplacian acts as the scalar operator $n$. Since the dimension of this subspace is $n-1$, this means there are $n-1$ linearly independent eigenvectors with eigenvalue $n$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are telling that $\lambda_1 \leq d_{max}$. Because we have a result from Brouwer and Haemers that says $\lambda_i\geq d_i-i+2$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. IT means that $\lambda_1\geq d_1+1$.

Comment: All eigenvalues of the *adjacency matrix* of a graph are bounded in range $(-d_{max}, d_{max}]$. When talking about the Laplacian ($Q$), it seems that Gerschgorin's circle theorem doesn't hold. I suppose what I am claiming isn't true since I had assumed it applied to the Laplacian. I misunderstood it's applicability.